# set onclick attribute in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick

When I run this `Javascript` code

```
var anchor = document.createElement("a");
anchor.style = "cursor:pointer;color:blue;";
 anchor.onclick = "this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);";
 anchor.innerHTML = "remove";
 div.appendChild(anchor);
```

My anchor is created as `<a style="cursor: pointer; color: blue;">remove</a>`
The onclick attribute is missing and the onclick function does not work.

Can I fix it?

Comment: Note that setting an element property doesn't necessarily affect the related attribute and *vice versa*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting it to a string and it does not actually set the attribute. Use a closure.

```
anchor.onclick = function() { this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode); };
```

ideally you would be using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

```
anchor.addEventListener("click", function(){ this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode); }, false);
```

Comment: Thank you. Only the solution with addEventListener works. But it's good to see what does not work as well.